# Custom Counting in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, counters, enumitem

is it possible to have an enumarated block, where the counter always adds by ten and not by one. If not how can I implement one with a custom counter?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}0}` is probably simplest. (or the equivalent `enumitem` option `label=\arabic*0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to define a new list that enumerates with a `0` suffix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{enumeratebyten}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumeratebyten]{label={\arabic*0.},ref={\arabic*0}}

\begin{document}

See Item~\ref{itm:first}:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{itm:first}First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

See Item~\ref{itm:last}:
\begin{enumeratebyten}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item \label{itm:last}Last
\end{enumeratebyten}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  
It is working now, but can you explain in which line the adding by ten is happening? (just interested)

Comment: @Spirou: `enumeratebyten` functions exactly the same as a regular `enumerate`, only adding the *suffix* `0.` to every `\item` label. So the count is still only incremented by one every time. The additional `ref` ensures the `.` is excluded from any `\ref`erences.